# Vectorized code for covariance matrix of crosscovariances

Tags: python, matlab, time-series, vectorization

## Introduction

I am trying to compute the asymptotic covariance matrix of sample autocovariances of multivariate time series. The derivations were shown by R. Roy in Biometrika Vol 76 Nº 4 (1989).

## Problem statement

In practice the computation uses a sequence of *K+1* *d* by *d* (autocovariance) matrices collected in 3D tensor **G**. Given **G**(:,:,u) we can define **G**(:,:,-u) = *transpose*(**G**(:,:,u)).

I want to build a (Sd^2) by (Sd^2) matrix **W** for some given integer S. The (i + j)(q + 1)-th row and (l + m)(p + 1)-th column element of **W** is given by the sum of

**G**(i, l, u)***G**(j, m, u+q-p) + **G**(j, l, u)***G**(i, m, u+q+p).

over u = -N:N. N is such that the third index of each term above is available.

Note that there are 6 indices to loop over: p and q (each going from 0 to S); i, j, l, m (each going from 1 to d).

My question is: what would be an efficient way to compute **W** in either Matlab or Python. Can I use something like Numpy's `einsum`?

Comment: I'm out of here for the math.... Are you sure that they are 3D matrices? Could you provide some code that at least builds an example on how the other (input) matrices are? + I found this in the mathworks-community: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/371283-how-to-operate-with-multidimensional-arrays-einstein-summation

Comment: @max I am new here so my reputation doesn't allow me to post images of the equations. **G** could be a 3D tensor or a sequence of K+1 dxd matrices.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal worked example? like a 2-by-2-by-2.